# Unable to create Campaign Hierarchy in Marketing Cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud

I have created a Campaign in marketing cloud but I am not able to find any way to create child campaign for it. Can we create Campaign Hierarchy in Marketing cloud just like we do in Sales Cloud?

Comment: This is currently not supported

Answer (score 1):

Campaign Hierarchy is currently not supported in Salesforce Marketing Cloud.

However, you may be able to achieve something closer by using [Tags and Filtering](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.mc_ca_filter_campaign_tags.htm&type=5)